# Can I build an Access chart including series with SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to build an Access chart that involves the three fields: `Days_Since` on the x-axis, `Rate` on the y-axis, and for the points to be grouped together by `Type` in a series. I am wondering if this is possible using SQL code. I have tried the built-in Access formatting features and they are not seeming to give me what I want. Also, I would like to note that I do not want any of my data summarized. My current SQL code is below and it is displaying without error.

`SELECT [Days_Since],[Rate] FROM [Change]`

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text table, not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an XYScatter chart with RowSource like:

```
SELECT Days_Since, IIf([Type]="A",[Rate],Null) AS TA, IIf([Type]="B",[Rate],Null) AS TB, IIf([Type]="C",[Rate],Null) AS TC
FROM Change;
```

Calculate as many "TYPE" fields are there are type values, hopefully not many.

Comment: I used your answer and the chart in design view is displaying as blank. Do you have any ideas what the error might be?

Comment: Assume you used your actual Type values in place of A, B, C. Graph works for me.

Comment: I did not put "" around my values because I thought since they were numbers they didn't need them. Works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your numbers are in a text type field? Field type dictates use of delimiters.